# Finding record with Dates

Tags: vba, date, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form, that is created like a calendar
.
When the form opens, update or requery it has to start on the current date. I've found the following code, but can only get it to work if I search the ID number.

```
Dim Today as Date, PickDate as Date
PickDate = "14-02-2021"

Me.Requery
With Me.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "DateP = " & PickDate
    If .NoMatch Then
        Msgbox "Record not found!", vbCritical
    Else
        Me.Bookmark = .BookMark
    End If
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Dim PickDate As Date

PickDate = #02/14/2021#

With Me.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "DateP = #" & Format(PickDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
    If .NoMatch Then
        Msgbox "Record not found!", vbCritical
    Else
        Me.Bookmark = .BookMark
    End If
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researching, i found out that scroll lock is fairly hard and unreliable in Access. Therefore i solved my problem in the query by only showing the current date and forward.